# Grails, Maps, and Memory Management

Tags: grails

Maps are a really common idiom inside of Grails and Groovy development, from what I've experienced.  Now that I've moved to a project that's doing more traditional Java, I'm getting hit hard by my Tech Lead for using `HashMaps`-->and I understand his reasoning why.  `HashMaps` use `StrongReferences`.  `StrongReferences` stick around any time there is a reference chain.

A common idiom I've seen in Groovy is to use maps to essentially take the place of POJOs.  (As in, you see it all over the place when browsing examples on the net.)

How does Grails get around this with all its map idioms?  Has anyone done memory profiling on their Grails applications?  Do maps like `params` hang around for awhile or do they predictably die and get collected with the User session terminates?  Or do I need to be as cognizant about using `Maps` in Grails as in Java?

=======Update====
Question above still stands, but the article used for reference is [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references):

Comment: `params` only lives for the duration of one request.

Answer (score 3):

Instances of `HashMap` are no different from instances of any other class in Java - as long as the map (respectively POJO) is reachable then all other objects referred to by the map entries (resp. fields in the POJO) will be reachable as well.  Once the map (POJO) instance is unreferenced all its entries (fields) which were reachable *only* through the map (POJO) will become eligible for garbage collection.

Maps are no better or worse than other classes in this respect.

Comment: I posted the article that made me raise the question.  It stands to reason then, that at least we need to be cognizant that we're not potentially putting a long-lived `StrongReference` into any of the default temporary `Maps`

Answer (score 1):

I don't buy the strong reference argument for not using Maps.

After you don't have any reference to a HashMap it becomes elligible for GC, and following that, all its elements not referenced by something else becomes elligible too.

For a map that holds its values until you don't have any way to access them, check out [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html).